# Cannot go to Windows 10 or Ubuntu anymore

Tags: dual-boot

I have Dual Booted Ubuntu and Windows and I used it for a few  days but today I (on Ubuntu) selected "Bootable" for Windows, I restarted and I could not access Windows nor Ubuntu. Using the Ubuntu install disk I am running Ubuntu from the disk after selecting "Try Ubuntu" and unchecked the box yet it still does not work. I would like to have an answer other than installing Ubuntu again because I don't want to. All of my files are still there though. I cannot do this everyday. Please help me fast!

Comment: What do you mean you "selected bootable for windows"? Are you sure that you actually installed the OS?  The live session you are using when you use "Try Ubuntu" doesn't install the operating system

Comment: I installed it. Windows and ubuntu. They would not start up and I did not want to install 2 copies of Ubuntu so I selected Try Ubuntu instead.

Comment: Where did you find documentation suggesting that you do that?  Manipulating system partitions in "Disks" could have caused the problem.  What **exactly** happens after you select Ubuntu in GRUB during boot?  You shouldn't need to install operating systems over and over. Are you doing this every time you reinstall?  Perhaps this or something else you're doing after installation is breaking your system.  Definitely do not manipulate Windows system partitions with Ubuntu tools or you will have to reinstall Windows too

Comment: I do not install systems over and over. The Grub boot used to come up but it does not.

Comment: It tells me to insert boot medium. And I will definitely not manipulate Windows partitions anymore in Ubuntu.

Comment: You will probably need to reinstall both operating systems.  Assuming a successful installation you do not need to do anything else to make the operating system bootable.  If you don't want any disk/partition/volume problems to persist after system reinstallations, you should first format (erase) the hard drive.  You can do this with the Disks app in a live session.  Make sure that you use GPT which should be preselected

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help.

Comment: A trick if you are putting both OS on the same drive.  After you format the disk as GPT, create two temporary dummy/placeholder partitions with any kind of file system to hold the place for Windows and Ubuntu, in that order. Before each installation, use the live session to delete the placeholder partition for the OS you are about to install. The automated installation for both Windows and Ubuntu will prefer to install to the unpartitioned free space.  This will also prevent windows from taking up the entire drive when it is installed first.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Everything is running properly now.